# Symfony FOSRest return html instead json

Tags: json, api, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

Hello I'm working on a migration symfony 2.7 -> symfony 3.4.
My API routes have not worked since I migrated. When I test them they send me an answer in 200 htlm / text instead of JSON. I have verfier my entities, my controllers and I try another configuration of the bundle but I got no result.

I work with jmserializer.

Here is my Bundle configuration.

```html
fos_rest:
  param_fetcher_listener:
    enabled: true
  body_listener: true
  format_listener: true
  view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
      json : true
      xml: true
    templating_formats:
      html: true
    force_redirects:
      html: true
    failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    default_engine: twig
  routing_loader:
    default_format: json
    prefix_methods: false
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. You can try it.

```
fos_rest:
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    body_listener:
        enabled: true
        default_format: json
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.json
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
        validate: true
        validation_errors_argument: validationErrors
    exception:
        enabled: false
        exception_controller: 'AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::showApiException'
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException': 404
            'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException': 400
            'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException': 403
            'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException': 403
            'Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ServerException': 500
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    param_fetcher_listener:
        enabled:  true
        force:    true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
```